# Datatables 'No Match Found'

Tags: php, json, ajax, datatables

I have a datatable that I'm using in server-side mode to retrieve data via AJAX. On the surface everything appears correct however, when I load the page I get "No Matching Records Found" displayed instead of the data displaying. The peculiar part is that it says it is showing the records "Showing records 1 to 2 of 2 entries".

The table HTML and JS is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#freebieslist").dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/config/getadvertisers",
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bFilter" : true,
        "sPaginationType" : "bootstrap",
        "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>"
    });

    $.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
        "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
    } );
});

</script>

<div class="row"><h1 class="pull-left">Advertisers</h1><div class="pull-right" style="margin-top:15px;"><a href="/config/addadvertiser" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/config/delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></div>    </div>
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">
    <table id="freebieslist" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="span1">&nbsp;</th><th>Advertiser</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>        </div>
```

The JSON being loaded is this:

```
{
    "sEcho": "1",
    "iTotalRecords": "2",
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": "2",
    "aaData": [
        [
            "2",
            "Test2"
        ],
        [
            "1",
            "Tester"
        ]
    ]
}
```

How to fix this so it actually displays the returned rows?

Comment: Per the (unselected) answer from OP below, ensure that your requests are actually coming back with data for the table to display. There was no issue with DataTables in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using datatables debugger in Chrome. I checked the AJAX result coming back (based on the get paramaters datatables was passing in) and found it was getting a null result set. A quick change in the server side code and things started working properly.

Comment: That would mean that "With Data Present" (per the title) is inaccurate. Please update the title to reflect the issue.

Comment: @AaronGibson Thankfully I have since gained permissions to do so. The title has been updated and the post corrected slightly.

Comment: @shruggernaut Thanks so much for the follow through.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!